# C++ Classes and Xcode

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I don't understand why Xcode gives me "Expected parameter declarator" error on line 3. 
Can you explain me what happens behind ?

```
class B;
class A {
    B b(this);
};

class B {
    B(A* a) { }
};
```

Comment: You should probably mention the error message you get. That way people googling for the error can find this post more easily.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that in-class member initialization needs to use either `=` or `{}`, not `()`, although I agree that "Expected parameter declaration" and "Expected ')'" are not particularly helpful error messages.

Also, at the point where you're declaring `b` to be initialized with the constructor of `B`, the compiler doesn't know about that constructor yet. Move the definition of `B` before `A` to solve this:

```
class A;

class B {
  public:
    B(A* a) { }
};

class A {
    B b = B(this);
    // or
    B b{this};
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `b` in the constructor of `A` and have the constructor `public`:

```
class A;

class B {
public:
    B(A* a) { }
};

class A {
public:
    A() : b(this) {}
    B b;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```